# Service script and shared libraries

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, services

I have the following simple script IPN in CentOS 6.5 in /etc/init.d/

```
#!/bin/sh
# chkconfig: 2345 05 06

cd /root/IPNHost

. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

start() {

    echo -n $"Starting..."
    /root/IPNHost/IPNHost
}

stop() {

    echo -n $"Stopping ..."
    killproc IPNHost
}

case "$1" in 
    start)
      start
      ;;
    stop)
      stop
      ;;
    restart)
      stop
      start
      ;;
    status)
      status IPNHost
      ;;
    *)

      echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
      exit 1
esac
exit 0
```

I have done the chkconfig stuff and realized that the script doesn't load successfully on startup. 
When I run

```
/etc/init.d/IPN start
```

it works perfectly fine.

However, when I do

```
service IPN start
```

It gives me "error while loading shared libraries: libippcore.so.7.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

How do I get IPN to see the IPP environment variables (consisting of the above library) when I run it using service IPN start? I assume this is why the service did not start when I rebooted the system.